# GTM + GA4 + window.gtag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I've recently moved from directly including my gtag script for a GA4 property to adding the GA4 property via GTM.

Throughout the website i'm firing tracking events using window.tag, and it appears that those events are no longer making it into the GA4 property.

Is there additional setup needed for this? When I test the events using GA Debug, I can see the dataLayer pushes being made in the GTM container, but they're not showing up in the GA4 reporting.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have added a GA4 configuration tag, there should be no additional setup necessary. However the datalayer pushes will not help you to debug, since byself they do not sent anything (they just provide data for configured tags within GTM). Look in the network tab for requests with a path that starts with "collect?v=2 (those are GA4 requests).  If they are not there, post your GA4 tag configuration, if they are there, the problem is not with GTM.

Comment: Thanks for the response @EikePierstorff! I can confirm the GA4 requests are appearing in the network tab, with the params I am expecting to see - with a 204 success response. The strange thing is when I directly include the GA4 property in the code, these events show up in GA4, but when the property is included via GTM, the events don't show up.

Comment: That's weird - by the time you see this in the network tab, GTM doesn't really enter the equation anymore. Did you by any chance change the measurement id at some point and forgot to publish (stupid question, I know, but then it happens to the best of us) ?

Comment: Negative! The more strange thing here is that the GA4 property *is* tracking, i'm showing up in the realtime reporting, and the out of the box GA4 events *are* being tracked, but the custom events that i'm sending myself using window.gtag(); aren't showing up, but they do show up when i'm including the GA script directly in the code, and not via GTM.